# ¿Cómo detectar cuando hay internet disponible en Android?

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo se puede obtener cuando hay disponibilidad de red Internet en Java de Android?

Necesito detectar cuando un dispositivo Android tiene conectividad a Internet, para así recibir o enviar datos.

Comment: Bueno creo que ya hemos respondido a tu pregunta, pero en eventuales futuras preguntas intenta añadir  "que has intentado hasta ahora para dar solución a tu problema", saludos.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Puedes usar esto para hacer las pruebas:

```
Log.e("netHabilitada", Boolean.toString(isNetDisponible()));
Log.e("accInternet",   Boolean.toString(isOnlineNet()));
```

Para comprobar si la red esta habilitada:

```
private boolean isNetDisponible() {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                                               getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo actNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (actNetInfo != null && actNetInfo.isConnected());
}
```

Para comprobar si hay acceso a internet:

```
public Boolean isOnlineNet() {

    try {
        Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.es");

        int val           = p.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (val == 0);
        return reachable;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Añadir (en Manifest.permission) tambien lo que necesites en los permisos por ejemplo estos si usas ambas:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Manifest.permission (link ingles):

[android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)

[android.permission.INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)

Comment: Grácias, la función isOnlineNet() va de fabula, porque a veces hay conexión al router pero no internet, sobretodo en bares, pubs etc...

Comment: Angel, @Webserveis me parece que el enfoque __"Para comprobar si hay acceso a internet:"__ esta erroneo ya que es posible desactivar la repuesta de ping en algunos servidores y dará una respuesta como si no hubiera acceso a Internet

Comment: @Hector basandose en que es posible que este desactivada la respuesta de ping, pues es posible la verdad no me lo habia planteado si esto ocurriera pero creo a para lo que es y sabiendo que puedes selecionar el servidor al que hace el ping, no veo porque no usar este metodo, yo siempre uso google para hacer ping sera por eso que no me lo plante nunca lo que usted comenta, (tambien podria usar su propio sevidor si lo tiene). Saludos

Comment: @Hector si usted conoce otro enfoque podria ponerlo como respuesta asi todos aprendemos otra manera mas eficiente y efectiva de hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Estimado por si no lo ha notado publiqué mi respuesta hace 50 minutos y si es posible que hacer ping a google de resultado, pero nadie nos asegura que Google tendrá siempre la respuesta de su ping activa

Comment: @Hector no se que estas tratando de decir con que usted publico su respuesta hace 50min yo acabo de recivir su comentario hace 10min, pero en fin yo le conteste. Saludos

Comment: Estimado, no estoy tratando de decir nada, sólo respondí a su comentario: **si usted conoce otro enfoque podria ponerlo como respuesta**, de hecho lo hice hace 50 min, eso es todo, que estes muy bien

Comment: @Hector Yo su forma de comprovacion no la uso, no digo que este mal, de echo la vi y ya esta, usted fue el que comento de mi forma, pues ya que estamos pienso que de causar error quizas el suyo lleve a mas falsos positivos pues isConnected() le dice si esta conectado a una red y no, si esta conectado a la red y esta tiene acceso a internet, pues usted podria estar conectado con acceso a una intranet y no ser adecuado para su app, pues en el caso del usuario que realiza la pregunta dice internet.

Comment: @Hector si tan trivial es usar internet, podria crear una lista de server para consultar, pero creo que para este caso solo con google iria bien el agregar mas server seria "sobrecomprobar" aunque se podrian hacer varias comprovaciones, eso dependeria de creador de la app. Si tuviera que usar su forma tambien implemtaria el metodo en el que compruebo que se tiene coneccion a internet, pero solo es mi opinion. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel con isConnected() podria hacer que mi aplicación en Android se conecte siempre a la misma red wifi?

Comment: Excelente solucion

Answer (score 9):

**Actualización Enero 2020:**

### A partir de Android 10 el uso de la clase  [NetWorkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) y sus métodos es obsoleto, ahora se debe hace uso de la clase `ConectivityManager` y metodo `getNetworkCapabilities()` o Clase `NetworkCapabilities`

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

---

**Ejecutar un proceso para realizar un ping no lo realizaría para eso se tiene la clase [NetWorkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) y sus métodos!**

> - Si requieres saber si hay internet disponible, debes revisar si
>     existe conectividad puedes usar [**isAvailable()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable())
> - Si requieres saber si existe conectividad y es posible establecer conexión , usa [**isConnected()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected())

Ejemplo:

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Muy importante agregar los permisos, para determinar el estatus de la red:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y para tener conectividad:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

Por otro lado puedes determinar el tipo de red si es [WiFi](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_WIFI) :

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
}
```

o si es [Móvil](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_MOBILE) :

```
public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}
```

Comment: Elena con esto solo es para saber si esta conectado a una red o para saber si hay comunicacion. hay veces que estamos conectados a una red pero no hay acceso a internet, me entiendes? funciona para saber si hay acceso?

Comment: Hola Manuel para ambas mediante la comprobación : networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected(); }

Comment: no me ha funcionado, probe con el ejemplo que tienes de `isOnline` pero tengo internet sin Acceso.

Comment: Crees que podría hacer que se conecte a la red Wifi que yo le indique y desactive los datos?

Comment: Hace tiempo recuerdo alguien pregunto como desactivar datos, anteriormente se podía con unos métodos que existian y se accesaban mediante reflection, pero ahora ya no existen, al parecer ordenar apagar datos no se puede, en cuanto Wifi puedes usar: WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); activar con:
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); o desactivar con:
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

Comment: Si puedo hacer que se conecte a una red wifi con eso de hecho ya publique la pregunta, <http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52293/como-indicarle-a-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-que-se-conecte-siempre-a-la-misma-red-wi> pero además yo quiero que se conecte a la red wifi que yo le indique osea especificarle el nombre de la red y el password

Answer (score 7):

Esta solución permite detectar si tu dispositivo Android está conectado a Internet, validando si existe una conexión por wifi o por redes móviles como 3G o 4G.

```
     ConnectivityManager cm;
     NetworkInfo ni;
     cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     boolean tipoConexion1 = false;
     boolean tipoConexion2 = false;

     if (ni != null) {
          ConnectivityManager connManager1 = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager1.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

          ConnectivityManager connManager2 = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager2.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

          if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
               tipoConexion1 = true;
          }
          if (mMobile.isConnected()) {
               tipoConexion2 = true;
          }

          if (tipoConexion1 == true || tipoConexion2 == true) {
               /* Estas conectado a internet usando wifi o redes moviles, puedes enviar tus datos */
          }
    } 
    else {
       /* No estas conectado a internet */
    }
```

Recuerda agregar los permisos correspondientes para ejecutar este código en tu manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Espero que ayude, saludos.

Comment: Crees que podría hacer que se conecte a la red Wifi que yo le indique y desactive los datos?

Answer (score 4):

Mi propia solución, para detectar si hay conexión a internet:
Resumiendo la función `isOnline` comprueba si la hay alguna conexión existente si está conectada y después comprueba si se puede consultar a google.es

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)     
         context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        RunnableFuture<Boolean> futureRun = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                if ((networkInfo .isAvailable()) && (networkInfo .isConnected())) {
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                        urlc.connect();
                        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No network available!");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        new Thread(futureRun).start();


        try {
            return futureRun.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: me marca error en : NetworkUtils

Comment: Si ya veo, es un método que lo tengo en una propia class, sustituye por     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

Answer (score 3):

Yo utilizo el siguiente metodo , espero te sirva :

```
public static boolean compruebaConexion(Context context)
{
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Recupera todas las redes (tanto móviles como wifi)
    NetworkInfo[] redes = connec.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < redes.length; i++) {
        // Si alguna red tiene conexión, se devuelve true
        if (redes[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connected = true;
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```