# ¿Como implementar AsyncTask al revisar conectividad?

Tags: android

Estoy usando un método que compruebe la conexión a internet, el problema es que la actividad se queda colgada momentáneamente al momento de que se hace esta comprobación, ese es el método de comprobación que encontré en internet:

Intente implementarlo, pero terminó con un objeto dentro del if y tampoco se como hacerlo con una `AsyncTask`.

```
if(isAvailable()){
    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexión!", 
                         "No hay conexión ", false);                    
} else{      
    // hago otra cosa 
}
```

El método `isAvaliable()` es el siguiente:

```
public Boolean isAvailable() {
    try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
        if(reachable){
            System.out.println("Internet access");
            // return reachable;
            return false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No Internet access");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Jesus, tengo una pregunta, cual es el objetivo de verificar internet? es decir, acaso en el else estas descargando datos? o para que usas la internet despues y cuando? es importante saberlo para darte una respuesta ajustada a tus necesidades sin hacer doble trabajo.

Comment: hola @rnd gracias por responder soy un poco nuevo en android y necesito mucha ayuda, aparte mi código y clases son un desorden bueno volviendo al tema, lanzo otra clase mediante un intent  que al presionar un boton  ejecuta un metodo  que envía datos a mysql via JSON y php,  en esa clase que se lanzo tengo implementado un AsyncTask para   ese procesos funcionando perfectamente, trate de implementar eso para el caso del if pero no logro acomodarlo, pero forzosamente requiero validar internet en esta clase para evitar guardar un dato en SQLite local, si requiere le puedo publicar todo el código

Comment: Con eso me basta... Gracias. En unas horas te contestaré

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como `isAvailable()` es un método sincrónico, no podrás hacerlo de la misma forma que lo haces ahora, es decir, un `if .. else`; ya que se debe esperar que se complete la tarea asincrónica antes de continuar (Aunque @Elenasys lo reutiliza, claro que puede reutilizarse, pero este enfoque es diferente, lo pone todo junto).

Para que sepas, el propósito de `AsnycTask` es realizar una tarea en segundo plano, **que interactúa con la interface de usuario** antes de empezar, durante su progreso y al finalizar. Así que hay muchas opciones (como ya te explicaron), aquí vamos a utilizarlo, pero para mostrar un dialogo de progreso simple para que el usuario sepa que algo esta pasando y que debe esperar.

Esta clase que dejo abajo, es re-utilizable a lo largo de tu proyecto. Por ejemplo antes de guardar los datos en el SQLite, tu sabras si es necesario o no en cada caso. No debes usarla como clase interna de tu Activity sino como clase independiente.

Código comentado:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Verificar internet y proseguir
 */
public class VerificarInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    // esta interface define como se procesara el resultado
    // es una forma personalizada de pasar a la AsyncTask tareas que 
    // debe realizar cuando termine, en este caso tiene 2 métodos,
    // que invocaremos según el resultado del ping.
    public interface EntoncesHacer {
        void cuandoHayInternet();
        void cuandoNOHayInternet();
    }

    // variables necesarias, el dialogo de progreso, el contexto de la actividad
    // y una instancia de EntoncesHacer, donde se ejecutan las acciones.
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private EntoncesHacer accion;

    // Constructor, recibe el contexto de la actividad actual,
    // y la instancia de EntoncesHacer
    public VerificarInternet(Context context, EntoncesHacer accion) {
        this.context = context;
        this.accion = accion;
    }

    // corre en el Thread de la UI antes de empezar la tarea en segundo plano.
    // aquí aprovechamos y mostramos el progress...
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // preparamos el cuadro de dialogo
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Verificando conexión a Internet");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        // llamamos al padre
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    // Esta es la tarea en segundo plano en si.
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // esta es una version modificada de tu codigo original, pero hace
        // mas o menos lo mismo.
        // la diferencia esta en la forma que invoca a ping, intenta mas 
        // veces y espera mas tiempo.
        // si la conexion a internet esta un poco lenta, el otro mecanismo
        // puede dar falsos negativos, este es un poco mas robusto al 
        // reintentar 2 veces y esperar mas tiempo.
        // si la conexion es normal, sera muy rapid
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {

            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("ping -c 2 -w 4 google.com");
            int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);

        } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
          catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return false;
    }

    // Esta es la tarea a realizar cuando termina la tarea en segundo plano
    // aquí de acuerdo al resultado llamaremos a uno u otro método
    // de la interface EntoncesHacer
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean resultado) {
        // llamamos al padre
        super.onPostExecute(resultado);

        // cerramos el cuadro de progreso
        dialog.dismiss();

        // de acuerdo al resultado del ping, se ejecuta una acción o la otra
        if (resultado) {
            accion.cuandoHayInternet();
        } else {
            accion.cuandoNOHayInternet();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego tienes que usarla de esta forma:

```
// aqui creamos la una instancia de VerificarInternet, que recibe el contexto 
// y la interface interna que se utiliza para decidir que hacer de acuerdo 
// a cada resultado.
VerificarInternet tarea =
        new VerificarInternet(NombreActivity.this, new VerificarInternet.EntoncesHacer() {
            @Override
            public void cuandoHayInternet() {
                // abrimos la nueva ventana.. este es el ELSE de tu if
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActividadPrimaria.this, 
                                              ActividadSecundaria.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                ActividadPrimaria.this.startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void cuandoNOHayInternet() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lo sentimos no hay internet", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
tarea.execute();
```

Ten en cuenta que tu aplicación deberá utilizar lo siguiente en el `manifest`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias @rnd me has salvado, funciona perfectamente, modifica algunas variable por que me pedía que fuesen final, pero todo aparentemente funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Después de dos años y todavía sigue siendo muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

AsynTask te permite realizar operaciones en segundo plano (background) y publicarlas (actualizarlas) en el hilo principal (UI thread).

> Trabaja con 3 tipos: Params, Progress y Result.
>
> Trabaja en 4 pasos: onPreExecute(), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) y OnPostExecute(Result):

Referencia oficial AsynTask: [Enlace](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Enlaces de interés en castellano

- [AsynTask en Android por Jarroba](http://jarroba.com/asynctask-en-android/)
- [AsynTask: Tareas Asíncronas en Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/12/android-asynctask-hilos/)
- [Tareas en segundo plano en Android (I): Thread y AsyncTask](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-i-thread-y-asynctask/)
- [Ejecutar una tarea en un nuevo hilo con AsyncTask](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-basico/36-unidad-5-entradas-en-android-teclado-pantalla-tactil-y-sensores/365-ejecutar-una-tarea-en-un-nuevo-hilo-con-asynctask)

Un breve ejemplo de como implemtarla.

```
private class EjemploAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // por ejemplo: progressBar.setMax(100); progressBar.setProgress(0);
        // ESTE SE EJECUTA EN EL HILO PRINCIPAL
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // RECIBES PARAMETROS Y TRATAS TAREA, ESTO SE EJECUTA EN UN HILO APARTE
        // RETORNAS 
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // por ejemplo: progressBar.setProgress(values[0].intValue());
        // ESTE SE EJECUTA EN EL HILO PRINCIPAL
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean resultado) {
        super.onPostExecute(resultado);
        // TAREA REALIZADA, ESTO SE EJECUTA EN EL HILO PRINCIPAL
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        // TAREA ASÍNCRONA CANCELADA
        // ESTE SE EJECUTA EN EL HILO APARTE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynctask es destinado para administrar varias tareas, Threads, en tu caso podrías usar únicamente [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)), y no sería tan necesario utilizar un **[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**:

```
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(isAvailable()){
                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexión!", "No      hay conexión ", false);
            } else{
                //....hago otra cosa 
            }

        }

     });
```

Si optas por usar un **[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**, esta sería la implementación:

```
public class AsyncConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

           //Ejecutas tu método para comprobar conexión, el cual regresa un valor boleano.
                return isAvailable(); 

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isAvalable) {

            //Se recibe el valor boleano del método doInBackground().
            // Se puede abrir el Dialogo en el Thread principal. 
                if(isAvalable){     
                     alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexión!", "No      hay conexión ", false);              
                } else{
                    //....hago otra cosa               
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

        }
```

Para ejecutar el Asynctask sería con:

```
    new AsyncConnectTask().execute();
```

Nota: Algo importante de comentar es que para detectar si tienes acceso a internet se puede realizar con el método:

```
      public static boolean isOnline() {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = getManager().getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
            }
```

el que usas podsría fallar en algunas versiones de sistema operativo, este método es el que describo en mi respuesta "[detectar cuando hay internet disponible en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3314/95) "

Comment: gracias @Elenasys es que tenia que meterlo forzosamente dentro del bundle y pude adaptar el de el compañero rnd... saludos