# ¿Se puede utilizar un Layout en 2 activities?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-drawerlayout

Buenas tardes.

Tengo una app que consume webservices (ya está terminada esa parte), pero ahora requiero que esa app funcione sin acceso a internet, ya tengo creada mi bd y ya tengo datos guardados.

Mi duda es si puedo utilizar un Layout para 2 activities diferentes: uno para cuando estoy conectado a wifi y el otro activity cuando no este usando wifi y trabaje de manera local.

Comment: La manera correcta de reutilizar vistas en Android es a travéz de Fragment.

Comment: Se puede perfectamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claro que se puede Hugo, la forma de realizar la carga del layout en tu Activity como sabes es a travez del método [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) para inflar el layout :

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    }
```

Puedes reutilizar el mismo layout en varias Activities, incluso validar en la misma Activity cargar uno u otro layout.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if(existeWIFI){
                    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
                }else{
                  setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_nowifi);
                }

     }
```

Comment: ok, Elenasys, y como puedo yo validar si tiene internet mi dispositivo o no tiene?

Comment: Revisa el primer método de mi respuesta  http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3314/95

Comment: y esa me serviria si tengo salida a internet desde mi android, lo que pasa es que yo quiero validar si el equipo tiene salida a internet usar el webservices como lo tengo hasta ahorita y si no tiene salida a internet use la bd que tengo en sqlite con los datos que tendria si uso el webservices

Comment: Elenasys abrir otro debate me ayudas, porfas   http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16775/error-al-generar-consulta-sqlite

Comment: Elenasys estas?

Comment: Hola Hugo que tal?

Comment: Disculpa Elenasys hay alguna manera de que cuando recorra mi arraylist solo recorra los que tiene un datos registrado

Comment: asi tengo mi for for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++), y por ejemplo yo en mi array tengo 4 detalles y de eso solo a 2 les inserte una cantidad en el edittext entonces ahora solo quiero que me recorra esas 2 afectadas para despues en mi update solo afecte esos 2 registro en mi bd de sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `SetConentView()`, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

La línea `setContentView(R.layout.main);` señala que hay una clase estática llamada `R.layout`, y que dentro de esa clase hay una constante entera llamada `main`, que apunta a una vista definida por un fichero de recursos *layout XML*.