# Error al generar Consulta Sqlite

Tags: android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

Buenas tardes

Seré consiso, estoy tratando de hacer una consulta usando `sqlite`

```
public ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ObtenerClienteZona()

{

    ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ArrayClienteZona = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();

    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona + " = " + settings.getInt("ONControlZonaCliente",0),null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0){

        while (aRS.moveToNext()){

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor newdetalle = new CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido))));
            ArrayClienteZona.add(newdetalle);

        }
    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayClienteZona;
}
```

En cual consulto mi tabla cliente donde zona es igual, a lo que yo tengo guardado en mi `sharedpreferences`, esa preferencia yo la tomo de un `alertdialog singlechoice`, el cual también lleno desde mi `base de datos` de `sqlite`

```
public void ObtenerZona() {

    ZonaArrayList = oBD.ObtenerZonas();

    final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
        //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
        zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();

    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
    alertdialog.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona");
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
    alertdialog.setSingleChoiceItems(zona, settings.getInt("ONControlZonaCliente",1), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("ONControlZonaCliente",ZonaArrayList.get(which).getId());
            editor.commit();

        }
    })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Mandar a llamar metodo Clientes con el filtro

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);

                    ObtenerClienteZ();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    AlertDialog alerdoalog = alertdialog.create();
    alerdoalog.show();
}
```

El problema es cuando selecciono la zona y se pasa a mi consulta truena y me arroja el siguiente error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol, PID: 5901
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at
>   mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.SqliteDB.ObtenerClienteZona(SqliteDB.java:258)
>                                                                                 at
>   mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.Clientes.ObtenerClienteZ(Clientes.java:270)
>                                                                                 at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.Clientes$5.onClick(Clientes.java:312)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Alguien me pueda ayudar deciendo como puedo acceder a mi preferences para poder realizar mi consulta.