# ¿cómo comprobar la conexión a internet?

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        String estado=networkInfo.getState().toString();
        Log.i("conexion",estado);
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Operaciones http
            new     LeerDeInternet().execute("http://www.floatrates.com/daily/ars.json");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Compruebe su conexión a internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

el problema es que aunque no tengo wifi y señal de red de datos no funciona(!) me devuelve el estado CONNECTED y por ende se ejecuta el proceso y queda esperando datos. La única forma de que me avise que compruebe la conexión es que desconecte la red movil.

Comment: falta revisar si existe conectividad, agregue un ejemplo usando el método sugerido.

Comment: Posible duplicada de http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-cuando-hay-internet-disponible-en-android

Answer (score 8):

El código que tienes sirve para comprobar si estás conectado a una red, pero no te dice si esa red tiene acceso a Internet o no. Por ejemplo, si estás en una red privada sin acceso a Internet, o en un *hotstpot* donde hasta que no pongas una clave no te den acceso a Internet, el código dirá que estás conectado aunque no tengas Internet.

Hay una [pregunta similar en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection). Según algunas de sus respuestas, después de comprobar que la conexión es correcta, deberías realizar una petición o hacer ping a un servidor que seguramente estará activo (p.e. Google o Facebook) para asegurarte de que además de haber conexión dicha conexión tiene acceso a Internet.

Esto se puede realizar de la siguiente manera (código adaptado de la [respuesta de Razzak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175890/3695983)):

```
public boolean conectadoAInternet() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    String comando = "ping -c 1 google.com";
    return (Runtime.getRuntime().exec (comando).waitFor() == 0);
}
```

Un problema sería que si Google está caído, aunque el dispositivo tenga acceso a Internet, dirá que no tienes. Una opción sería añadir algún tipo de *fallback*, por ejemplo si Google no devuelve el *ping*, comprobar Facebook o Twitter o Amazon... si ninguno de ellos responde, puedes estar seguro de que no hay Internet (o de que el mundo se está acabando :P)

Comment: +1, necesitaba esto hace algún tiempo y usaba el ejemplo que tiene el OP, tu solución, además de práctica, es elegante, gracias.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro! por alguna razón no me funcionó el método en el if() me ponía que no podía resolverlo, pero usé un método similar. Saludos!!!

Answer (score 6):

Una cosa es obtener si tu red esta habilitada y la otra es obtener si en realidad hay conectividad dependiendo de los proveedores, los proveedores más usados son tipo móvil (`TYPE_MOBILE`) y tipo WiFi (`TYPE_WIFI`).

Lo que debes revisar son dos cosas:

Si existe conectividad con [**isAvailable()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()) y si existe conectividad y es posible establecer conexión con [**isConnected()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected())

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

La forma en que usarias el método sería:

```
 if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
            // Operaciones http
            new     LeerDeInternet().execute("http://www.floatrates.com/daily/ars.json");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Compruebe su conexión a internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

No olvides los permisos:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

**No considero apropiado usar la clase InetAddress o realizar un ping para revisar si hay conectividad y es posible realizar la conexión, para este objetivo son los métodos contenidos en el SDK de la clase [NetWorkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html)** que son:

> [**isAvailable()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()): Indica si la conectividad de red es posible.
>
> [**isConnected()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()): Indica si existe conectividad de red y es
>   posible establecer conexiones y enviar datos.

e incluso

> [**isConnectedOrConnecting()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnectedOrConnecting()) : Indica si la conectividad de red
>   existe o está en proceso de establecerse.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, gracias como siempre por responder! El método que sugieres lo probé y si no tengo wifi encendido y la red móvil no devuelve datos queda realizando el intento de conexión. Saludos!

Comment: @LosMilton siempre WiFi tiene la prioridad, cuando tienes encendido Wifi y la red movil el provider habilitado es Wifi, si desconectas Wifi y tienes red movil este deberia ser el proveedor. Es un poco raro lo que me comentas este metodo es el que uso actualmente, de hecho la comprobacion: networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected() asegura que tengas conectividad y si por medio de la red es posible establecer conexion,

Comment: Usé este Log para saber que devolvía
        String estado=networkInfo.getState().toString();
        Log.i("conexion",estado);
y estado = CONNECTED.
Opté por hacer un ping a google

Comment: igual, como siempre muy clara la explicación, gracias!!!