# Método que comprueba conexión a Internet Android

Tags: android

Tengo un `splash screen` en mi aplicación donde quiero que compruebe mediante un método si hay conexión a internet. Si la hay que prosiga con la ejecución y si no detecta conexión a internet que cierre la aplicación de forma correcta con un mensaje de error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para comprobar la conexión a internet puedes ver:

**[¿cómo comprobar la conexión a internet?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41864/c%C3%B3mo-comprobar-la-conexi%C3%B3n-a-internet/41997#41997)**

A partir de Android 10 el uso de la clase NetWorkInfo y sus métodos es obsoleto, ahora se debe hace uso de la clase ConectivityManager y metodo getNetworkCapabilities() o Clase NetworkCapabilities

Usa el método especificado:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 if (connectivityManager != null) {
       NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                return true;
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                return true;
            }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

 return false;

}
```

y agregar los permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

La implementación se realizaría de esta forma:

```
if(isOnline(getApplicactionContext()){
   //Continua...Aquí puedes agregar el intent a MainActivity.

}else{
  //termina aplicación, si estas en SplashActivity.
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No existe conexión a Internet, intente mas tarde...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   finish();
}
```

#### Metodo anterior.

<strike>public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }</strike>

Answer (score 2):

Usa esto para ver si el dispositivo tiene conexión a internet.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class CheckNetworkConnection {

    public static boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()
                    && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                    && netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder comprobar la conexión a internet deberás tener puestos los siguientes permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Por otro lado yo utilizo el siguiente método para comprobar si la conexión está disponible:

```
    /**
     * Comprobar si existe conexión a internet
     * 
     * @param context contexto de la actividad que la llama.
     * 
     * @return true si esta disponible, false en caso contrario
     */
    public static boolean conexionDisponible(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        try {
            if (connectMgr != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    Network[] networks = connectMgr.getAllNetworks();
                    if (networks != null) {
                        for (Network net : networks) {
                            NetworkInfo infonet = connectMgr.getNetworkInfo(net);
                            if (infonet.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = connectMgr.getAllNetworkInfo(); // deprecated en api 23
                    if (netInfo != null) {
                        for (NetworkInfo net : netInfo) {
                            if (net.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e){
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();

        //Para saber si está conectado al wifi o al 3g
//          if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
//              if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
//                  // connected to wifi
//                  Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
//                  // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
//                  Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              }
//          } else {
//              // not connected to the internet
//          }
        }
    }
```

Aunque te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) que viene todo muy bien detallado.

Por último la comprobación que debes hacer en la splash screen deberá ser algo como lo siguiente:

```
if (!conexionDisponible(getApplicationContext())) {
    //mostrar el mensaje de error
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay conexión a Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //salir de la aplicación
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    }else{
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```