# ¿Como validar en Android Studio que sea posible la navegacion por internet? Sin NetworkInfo

Tags: java, android-studio, wifi, datos

Me he encontrado mucha información que hacer referencia al NetworkInfo pero no me resuelve mi duda ya que en la documentación de google aparece como obsoleto. Quiero validar exactamente que exista una red habilitada como el wifi o los datos, pero que a pesar de que estén activas y por ejemplo no se tenga datos para la nevegacion sea posible decirle al usuario que no tiene datos para la navegación o en el caso del wifi que diga que no tiene acceso a Internet, espero puedan ayudarme gracias !

Es lo que intentado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes actualizar usando los nuevos métodos, si revisas la documentación la clase [NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) es obsoleta desde API 29, por lo tanto sus métodos como [getActiveNetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()) también lo están.

Lo recomendable es cambiar el código para detectar conectividad, se realizaría de esta forma usando la clase `NetworkCapabilities`.

**Mostrar mensaje si existe red WiFi o Datos**

usa el siguiente método el cual determina si existe o no conectividad `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR` (datos) o `TRANSPORT_WIFI` (WiFi) y muestra un mensaje en caso de no existir alguna:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                // Datos
                return true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "No existe conexión Datos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                // WiFi
                return true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "No existe conexión Wifi!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

El método anterior lo usarías de esta forma para determinar si hay conexión:

```
  if (isOnline(getApplicationContext()){
     //Hay conexión
  }else{
     //NO hay conexión
  }
```

Revisa:

[Método que comprueba conexión a Internet Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74279/m%c3%a9todo-que-comprueba-conexi%c3%b3n-a-internet-android)

Comment: Si comprendo que verifica que haya un estado de conexion, lo probe pero la cuestion esta en que verifique que aunque esten habilitadas tanto el wifi y los datos se asegure de que pueda navegar en internet, por ejemplo los datos prendidos pero se acabaron para poder navegar y arrojar un mensaje de que no se puede navegar o que los datos se acabaron, mismo caso para el wifi , hay manera de validar eso?