# ¿Como indicarle a mi aplicación Android que se conecte siempre a la misma red wifi?

Tags: android, android-studio

El dispositivo en el cual estará la aplicación siempre estará en el mismo lugar pero en ese mismo lugar hay muchas redes Wifi.

Investigando encontre que existe la clase: WifiManager y sus métodos: WIFI_STATE_ENABLED, getConfiguredNetworks bueno no se si se pueda lo que quiero hacer y también no tengo idea de por donde empezar alguien que me indique si es posible o no?

UPDATE

Por lo visto lo que menciono anteriormente si es posible. Hasta el momento puedo lograr que se conecte a una red wifi a la que ya haya estado conectado previamente con lo siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo no se como hacerle para especificarle a que red Wifi debe conectarse

Comment: Si, si es posible, te dejo aquí un [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically) (en inglés) que te puede ser de ayuda

Comment: @Jorius wow nunca se me ocurrió investigarlo en Ingles muchas gracias al parecer si es lo que busco.

Comment: @Jorius siguiendo el ejemplo no me marca error de sintaxis pero al momento de abrir la app se cierra, nose que pueda estar mal, también hize una actualización porque de otro modo logro que se conecte a una red wifi previamente utilizada no se por donde continuar.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el logcat a ver que pueda estar sucediendo?

Comment: Si revise el de Android Studio que se encuentra en AndroidMonitor pero no me muestra ninguna excepción

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se desea especificar a que Red Wifi deseamos que se conecte nuestra app podemos utilizar el siguiente código:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String networkSSID = "REDWIFI";
    String networkPass = "password";
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if ((wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conectando a WIFI...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```