# No accede a Internet desde WebView en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, webview-android

tengo una aplicación la cual reproduce videos que tengo en un servidor multimedia, hace poco me di cuenta que en varios dispositivos no reproduce por falta de acceso a internet o asi lo muestra, tengo un metodo para verificar la conexion a internet y si no la tiene muestre un Toast en la pantalla, la versión en la que pruebo y no funciona es la 7.0, la he probado en otros dispositivos y funciona bien.

Asi tengo los permisos del manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Esta es la parte del WebView

```
if (reachable) {
        final Activity activity = this;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.getLoadWithOverviewMode();
        webView.loadUrl(urlvideo);
        new cargarurl().execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_conection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

y con lo siguiente verifico si tiene conexion a internet antes de mostrar o cargar la url

```
public Boolean isOnlineNet() {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.es");

        int val = p.waitFor();
        reachable = (val == 0);
        return reachable;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cual es la url de tu video?, no creo sean permisos de internet, es el navegador o los codec que soporta el dispositivo.

Comment: @Jorgesys esta es una de las URL https://cloudup.com/iBWRrCHtV5t, reproduce en otros dispositivos

Comment: No has probado en otras versiones de Sistema operativo android verdad? @LeonardoHenao.

Comment: Si, probe con android 4.0, 4.4, 5.0, 6.0 y todos me funcionan

Comment: Revisa el logcat que muestra por favor Leonardo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Había comentado, aquí que eso que tratas realizar es incorrecto, revisa mi respuesta:

[¿Cómo detectar cuando hay internet disponible en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-cuando-hay-internet-disponible-en-android)

Agrega los permisos :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y usa este método:

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Cuando no se carga un video dentro de un `WebView`, las causas generalmente son:

- No existe conexión a internet.
- Codec de video no soportado.
- El navegador contiene objetos javascript no soportados. Recuerda que un `WebView` en Android es un navegador limitado.

En este caso al analizar tu video,

https://cloudup.com/iBWRrCHtV5t

este tiene un `Mime Type` no soportado por dispositivos android para reproducción de video:

> **VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/sorenson**

Comment: probé el método que colocas y me funciono a la perfección, con respecto al vídeo,  tengo cerca de 900 vídeos en esa nube y todos están en una aplicación, solamente que cambie de teléfono por uno que tiene la versión 7.0 de android y me generaba error al reproducir los vídeos haciendo la prueba desde android studio, para que los reprodujera me tocaba generar la apk en release he instalarla, pero con el método que me diste ya funciona todo muy bien, aunque se que los comentarios no es para decir gracias, pero no esta de mas darte las gracias después de mi explicación.