# ¿ como evitar que el webView muestre, "pagina web no disponible", y mostrar un html local. en Kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

actualmente estoy practicando con `Webview` y este pedazo de código funciona pero un ejemplo que el dispositivo no tenga conexión a internet que muestre un html local.

aqui mi código en `Kotlin`:

```
 package com.tutorialkart.webviewexample

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ya pude resolverlo.

No quise meter mucho código y solo hice un ping para verificar si existe conexión a Internet y devuelve un boleano y con eso hago la condición para mostrar el sitio en el webview.

dejo el código por si alguien mas lo necesita :)

```
    package com.tutorialkart.webviewexample

import android.content.Context
import android.icu.util.RangeValueIterator
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.AvailableNetworkInfo
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {

        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        try {

            val ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")
            val exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor()
            return exitValue == 0

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true

        val va = isNetworkAvailable();
        if (va == true){
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
        }
        else{
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html")
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: 2 recomendaciones, editar y explicar tu código ayudaría mucho no solo a elevar la calidad de tu respuesta sino además a que otros usuarios la comprendan mejor, segundo en cuanto te sea posible marcarla como aceptada y de este modo saber que esta es la solución.

Comment: **No es recomendable usar val ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")**, puede estar disponible la red pero no tener conectividad, para verificar conectividad usa la clase networkInfo del Android SDK, networkInfo.isConnected realiza esta tarea.

Comment: trate de usarlo pero me marcaba como obsoletos "activeNetworkInfo” y “isConnected”.  'getter for activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes crear el directorio `/assets` en tu proyecto y guardar ahí tu archivo `.html` "local", el cual se mostrará cuando no se tenga conexión a internet.

[Como poner y mostrar un archivo html en mi proyecto de android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82505/como-poner-y-mostrar-un-archivo-html-en-mi-proyecto-de-android-studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Kotlin, detectar conexión a internet

**Actualización Enero 2020**

Actualmente se debe detectar conectividad usando la clase forma NetworkCapabilities, (ya que el método anterior es obsoleto) , puedes usar el método:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

---

**Versión Kotlin** :

```
fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
}
```

[Versión **Java:**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90858/no-accede-a-internet-desde-webview-en-algunos-dispositivos/90883#90883)

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Para detectar conectividad, requieres los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo, que cargaría el html llamado `mypage.html` almacenado en el directorio `/assets` de tu proyecto en caso de no existir conectividad, de otra forma se mostrará la url `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView);
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        if (isOnline(context = applicationContext)) {
            webView!!.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/")
        } else {
            webView!!.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html")
        }


    }

    fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
    }

}
```

Comment: hay algunas funciones como "activeNetworkInfo" y "isConnected" me marcan como obsoletos.  'getter for activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Comment: Si usas Kotlin ya no es necesario networkInfo.isAvailable solo necesitas networkInfo.isConnected , para usar connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo necesitas el permiso     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: gracias ya pude resolverlo :)