# Comprobar conexión a Internet en dispositivo Android

Tags: java, android

deseo comprobar si actualmente el dispositivo cuenta con conexión a Internet, no quiero comprobar si esta conectado a wifi o datos móviles, solo quiero comprobar que se pueda navegar, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    String host = "www.google.com";
    int port = 80;
    Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 2000);
        socket.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException es) {}
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y este es el código del boton:

```
public void deleteData(View view) {

   if(isInternetAvailable()) {
       Log.w("SI","INTERNET");
   }
    else {
       Log.w("NO","INTERNET");
   }
}
```

Ahora, cuando estoy conectado a wifi o con datos móviles encendidos y hay conexión a internet, muestra el Log correcto; pero cuando en el dispositivo los datos celulares están encendidos pero no hay conexión para navegar (sin mb, ni saldo) debería mostrar en el Log "NO" "INTERNET" , pero me sigue mostrando "SI" "INTERNET". ¿Cuál podría ser mi error? Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Hola Luis, te sugiero revisar en el sitio, esta información ya se encuentra en el sitio. Debes diferenciar entre conectividad y si es posible establecer la conexión. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-cuando-hay-internet-disponible-en-android/3314#3314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu forma de validar la conexion a internet es que solo esta validando la existencia de una interfaz de red (wi fi o datos). Hay formas de validar la existencia de conexion de una interfaz de red, como la siguiente.

```
 public boolean activeNetwork () {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();

        return isConnected;

    }
```

Pero de nuevo, si el dispositivo tiene activados los datos, pero no tiene saldo por decirlo de alguna manera, este metodo seguira retornando true incluso sin poder acceder a internet. La mejor forma de hacer esto es la siguiente.

```
 public class CheckInternetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        private Context context;

        public CheckInternetAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            assert cm != null;
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnected();


            if (isConnected) {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                            (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                                    .openConnection());
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                            urlc.getContentLength() == 0)
                        return true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error checking internet connection", e);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "No network available!");
                return false;
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("TAG", "result" + result);

            if(result){
                // do ur code
            }

        }


    }
```

No olvides los permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

y se usa de la siguiente manera

```
new CheckInternetAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute();
```

Este metodo lo he usado antes y me ha funcionado muy bien y lo he sacado de este post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out

De la segunda respuesta, asi que si mi respuesta te sirve te solicito que visites el post y tambien le des un punto al autor original.

La explicacion del uso de este ultimo metodo es el siguiente. Se hace uso de una peticion asincrona a una api la cual resuelve una respuesta con un body vacio, por lo cual es bastante rapido y no consume muchos datos moviles. De esta manera puedes validar si tienes o no conexion a internet de forma verdadera.

Por ultimo cabe resaltar que si vas a realizar una peticion a una api remota no hay necesidad de validar si hay conexion a internet o no. Realiza tu peticion y en caso de el codio te arroje una expecion puedes validarla y con base en ella deducir cual fue el error y comunicarlo al usuario. Una de estas excepciones es por supuesto no tener acceso a internet.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo probaré. Dime esto también funciona cuando esta conectado a una red wifi pero no hay conexión a  internet en dicha red?

Comment: @JohnFredyTrujilloOrtega Información sobre esto se encuentra en el sitio, sería bueno dirigir a los usuarios a lo que se tiene actualmente en SOes.

Comment: Pues estuve buscando pero no encontre ninguna respuesta que mencionara todo lo que digo (en SOes) por eso puse el post en ingles e intente explicarlo un poco. Si encuentras una respuesta duplicada por fa me dices y edito la respuesta

Comment: Hola, he probado tu respuesta y funciona bien! hay un detalle y es cuando el dispositivo esta con datos móviles pero sin saldo, la respuesta tarda un poco (aprox 4 segundos), como podria reducir ese tiempo? ya que cuando no esta conectado a a wifi o datos o cuando esta conectado pero si hay saldo, la respuesta es inmediata, gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Puedes disminuir el tiempo de time out, para que no espere tanto tiempo una respuesta, pero ten cuidado, no puedes bajarlo demasiado ya que cualquier tipo de peticion necesita un tiempo para recibir una respuesta. En la linea urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); Podrias bajarlo a la mitad y hacer pruebas con ello (si el comentario te sirve no olvides darle un punto)