# ¿Como verificar en android si hay una conexión a internet?

Tags: java, android

Alguien en la comunidad sabe de algún método que me ayude a verificar conexión en internet que no sea verificación si existe red si no Internet tal vez haciendo un ping a google , pero que el tiempo de verificación si existe esta conexión sea mínimo.

El siguiente código estoy probando pero el tiempo de respuesta no es tan bueno

```
public class CheckInternetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        private Context context;

        public CheckInternetAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Boolean conexion = false;
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            assert cm != null;
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnected();



            if (isConnected) {
                try {

                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection());
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200){
                        conexion = true;
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error sin conexión", e);
                    conexion =  false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Red no disponible");
                conexion = false;
            }



            return conexion;
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: que has probado?

Comment: Posible duplicado de: [¿Cómo detectar cuando hay internet disponible en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-cuando-hay-internet-disponible-en-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Usa la clase ConectivityManager